# Change arrow head type for quiver plot in PGFPLOTS

Tags: pgfplots

I have multiple quiver plots in one figure and want to distinguish between them by the arrow head type/ style.

Can anyone help me, how the head can be changed?

Thanks,
Peter

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[ ]
  \addplot[quiver={u=0,v=x},-stealth] {1}; 
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Peter, welcome to the site! You can format your code sample by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button in the editor (or pressing Ctrl+K).

Comment: If I compile your code, I get a quiver plot with `stealth` arrow heads. If I change `-stealth` to some other arrow head type, like `-latex` or `->`, the arrow head in the picture also changes. Does that not work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your great help! Or rather sorry for the too easy question... Sometimes pgfplots is easier than I assume...

Answer (score 4):

You can change the arrow head type by putting `-stealth`, `-latex`, `->` (or any of the other arrow head keys) in the `\addplot [...]` options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[ ]
  \addplot[quiver={u=0,v=x},-stealth] {1}; 
  \addplot[quiver={u=0.1*x,v=-x},->, red] {1}; 
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```